# importing python script for dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have python script data.py, where I have two dictionaries code (without using function). I want to use these two dictionaries in another python script file. What is the process to do that? Is creating function only way to import another python script?

```
print(dict(d1))
print(dict(d2))
```

Comment: You can simply `import data` and then access the dictionaries with `data.d1`

Comment: Please, show your `data.py`. Basically `import data`, then you can reference `print(data.d1)`

Comment: Yes! It worked, although take lil bit time to reload module, is this normal to take time to reload? @ForceBru

Comment: thanks it worked. but takes time to reload module. @buran